# Static Actionscript code analysis possibilities

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, code-analysis, static-analysis

I want to see class, function and variable/property, dependencies visually, like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Screenshots.aspx), but for ActionScript 2 or AS3 code.

Any programs or ideas?

Use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) in some way?

[FlexUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219549/automated-testing-non-ui-for-existing-flash-component)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update Nov 2018:**

It would appear that Structure101 ([new download page](https://structure101.com/downloads/)) no longer has an ActionScript variant.

**Original answer, links outdated:**

Download [Structure101g](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/downloads/structure101/g.php) and select the Actionscript flavor after installing the software.

I've confirmed that it is able to map out class level and even function call dependencies in Flex/AS3 projects, and generate a visual map of the same.

Take a look at the attached screenshot.

> (non-SSL link dead: i40.tinypic.com/e8qptu.png)

Hope that helps.

Comment: **+550** - Thank you for exploring this software and confirming that it can do function level mapping. I suppose Structure101 could do the same for C++ and Java code. Nice. Congrats on winning the bounty! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 8):

Far from a complete solution, but to start you may want to use flex SDK ASDoc to generate the class path structure in a single XML (thanks to the *-keep-xml -skip-xsl* arguments).

Thereafter you could probably get a nice result if you have a play with graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php).

Automating it all via ANT and you're sorted ; )

Answer (score 4):

The Flex SDK compilers have a `-link-report` argument that will give you some good information about the classes compiled into the SWF and their dependencies.

See [Examining Linker Dependencies](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/performance_06.html#211202) from the Flex 3 documentation for more information.

Answer (score 4):

[ItDepends](http://code.google.com/p/it-depends/), a Visual browser for class and package dependencies in Flex applications.

It lacks the visualization capabilities of NDepends but its a big step up from trying to make sense of link reports. Its source is there so if one was sufficiently motivated it could be extended with visualizations.

Comment: It can't draw pretty graphs, but it doesn't require Windows. +1

Answer (score 4):

I was going to post a link to Big Kahuna Burger's Link Report Visualizer, but I see that darrinm has found a much better tool.

Still, could be of some use

[LinkReportAIR](http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/03/08/air-link-report-visualizer/)

Comment: This tool does nice visual usage breakdowns (seen WinDirStat?) and allows you to sort columns.  Unfortunately, you can't copy/paste any data from it.  Still a neat tool.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime you an also get information about individual classes via the describeType method (Part of flash.utils). It returns an XML document that describes the class you give to it.