# reverse engineering or documentation tools for flex/actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, reverse-engineering

I have inherited a flex project which is sadly not documented. Im looking for a documentation generation tool / class diagram generater or something like that which works with actionscript. There are around a 1000 class files and I don't have the time to step through all the code in debug.

I have tried a few tools like Doxygen (set the language to java) and NaturalDocs but that didn't work out too well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea for the document generation, BTW, would it really help with a huge bulk ASDoc ?

Regarding the diagram generation I posted an answer for the following question. Not sure the guy ever found out, I'm interested about the matter as well.

[Static Actionscript code analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548830/actionscript-code-analysis/549225#549225)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this just a pointer, but Enterprise Architect supports round-trip source code engineering for Actionscript (it's the only tool that can generate UML from AS source code, that I'm aware of).

I haven't used it much, just tried it some time ago, but perhaps it's worth a shot. I think it has a 30-day free trial.

Comment: i tried the trial version but had no luck with it. maybe i configured it incorrectly but my uml output was always empty

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is looking for an answer, I would recommend using [Crocus Modeller, UML modeling tool for AS3 & FLex](http://crocusmodeller.com) with reverse engineering feature.