# Flash Dependency Checking?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, dependencies, classpath

So I've been working on some Flash stuff for a client, and we're recently moving everything into a svn repo, so I need to get all of the class files to be included in the repo.

The issue I'm having is that I usually am the only one working on flash stuff, and this project is a little old, so I'm not absolutely sure which class files are being used by this particular app, as I have multiple classPaths set so I can always include utility functions (like JSON encoding classes, and other small classes I have written and like to re-use).

Does anyone know of a simple way of either keeping a document relative classPath (like a com folder in the same folder as the .fla) synched with my external class files that it uses, (this solution would be optimal, so I could avoid any redundancy in classes when I want to edit), or alternatively, just a simple way to see what class files the fla is using, so I can track them down and put them in a document relative spot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can suggest is the [linker dependencies report](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=performance_06.html#211202) generated by the Flex compilers.  There's some decent [prior discussion of tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548830/actionscript-code-analysis) utilizing said reports here on SO.